# in app purchase test account not working in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

we are testing in app purchase with sandbox test account and at time of testing it shows Verification and after  verification of payment info when i tried to test in app purchase it redirects me to app store and app store shows time out

am i doing anything wrong?
i have also created three more sandbox test account for testing in app purchase. but same error occurs.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: what happen when you press "Continue" ?

Comment: Check if everything is on on Apple side before you test it: http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Comment: I'm also facing same problem since 2 days and tried almost every solutions from stackoverflow but not found workaround so possible that problem from apple side(hope so).

Answer (score 5):

For me to fix this issue, I simply registered a new user in iTunesConnect, but I set their store to 'USA'.

Comment: great man.....i have tried this and it's working...Thanks...+1 for this solution.

Comment: @Babi, like to check if you are facing issues with in-app purchase in live environment? I am able to test it if I change it to USA store, but in live environment it just crashed out at "didReceiveRespond". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890386/ios-app-crashed-after-download-from-appstore

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Create the test account online.

Step 2: Log out of the current account in Settings.app > App Store.

Step 3: DO NOT log into the test account yet.

Step 4: Build and run your app on the device, signed with a Development profile (not ad-hoc).

Step 5: Make your purchase. It'll give the UIAlertView, via which you sign into the test account.

If you sign into your test account via any other mechanism, and especially if you add credit card info, that test account will be permanently broken. I recommend trying my steps above with a brand new test account. To make them easier to remember, I usually suffix my test account names with a number, and increment it each time.

Comment: I have tried this with new 3 test accounts and it's not working mate...do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Thank you a TON for this one. Not logging in is key. Also helpful to have the notes about credit card, dev profile.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug from apple server side. because from last couple of days many test accounts are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Been having similar problem, getting better by doing this;

Create a new account in iTunes connect - DO NOT LOG IN OR ANYTHING! (this seems to be important)
From the device (not simulator) sign out of any account.
Run the app and try.

My problem is now confirming I have some kind of purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 12,There is a separate section to sign in sandbox account in iphone settings. This allow us to test in sandbox without sign out from iTunes account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. The verification is about filling up some missing fields, but you don't have control once the user press `Continue` button, so chances are there's something wrong with the itunes verification site; just keep trying a while after.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when the test user was not in the correct Apple developer Account. Make sure in iTunes Connect, that your test user is indeed in Test Users.