# iOS app crashed after download from Appstore

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

My approved app crashed after it was downloaded from the Appstore. Baring all other circumstances, I am wondering if it's due to the fact that I have yet to get approval from Facebook for using their login mechanism and xmpp chat?

Hope someone can verify this?

Comment: there is some issue with in-app purchase

Comment: @Hemant, are you facing the same issue with in-app purchase? Mine's approved.

Comment: @Hermant, just to verify, you are referring to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784269/in-app-purchase-test-account-not-working-in-ios/18785905#18785905

Comment: No that thread was related to test accounts that we use during run time. and your app is live now. i said that because in line number 4 of debug log they have mentioned `storekit`

Comment: No i faced that issue during development time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you built the bug yourself: In your method `-[AppDelegate productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:]` you are accessing an array with an index out of bounds.

Check the system log to see what the actual bad index is.

Comment: I am currently using in-app purchase. The only occurrence of productRequest:didReceiveResponse is as follows. I am calling the first item in the array, ie '0'. And this in-app item has also been approved.  -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    product= [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
}

Comment: @ngzhongcai Well, as I said, the problem is clear: You are trying to access an element of an array with an index that does not exist. If `response.products` is the only array you touch in that method, it's obviously empty.

Answer (score 2):

After reading your comment on Nikolai Ruhe's answer (which is correct), it is quite obvious that the reason for the crash is that you don't check that `response.products` contains any products at all before accessing its first element. 
It still should not happen that you're not receiving the correct product in the response (especially if it always worked and the in app purchase product was accepted with the app), but you didn't manage this case and that is what's causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

With given debug logs this is clear , this problem is related to your in-app purchase.
You should review your in-app purchase implementation.